# Telegram Bot: a set of characters break out of HTML escape

Tags: python, utf-8, escaping, python-telegram-bot, html-escape-characters

I have a game telegram bot which uses first name - last name pairs to spell out a top chart of users in a chat by their score. Screenshot example below:

[image: normal markup]

So, every user has a link to them. The actual code to generate a link:

```
from html import escape as html_escape

EscapeType = typing.Literal['html']


def escape_string(s: str, escape: EscapeType | None = None) -> str:
    if escape == 'html':
        s = html_escape(s)
    elif escape is None:
        pass
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(escape)
    return s


def getter(d):
    if isinstance(d, User):
        return lambda attr: getattr(d, attr, None)
    elif hasattr(d, '__getitem__') and hasattr(d, 'get'):
        return lambda attr: d.get(attr, None)
    else:
        return lambda attr: getattr(d, attr, None)


def personal_appeal(user: User | dict, escape: EscapeType | None = 'html') -> str:
    get = getter(user)

    if full_name := get("full_name"):
        appeal = full_name
    elif name := get("name"):
        appeal = name
    elif first_name := get("first_name"):
        if last_name := get("last_name"):
            appeal = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
        else:
            appeal = first_name
    elif username := get('username'):
        appeal = username
    else:
        raise ValueError(user)

    return escape_string(appeal, escape)


def user_mention(id: int | User, name: str | None = None, escape: EscapeType | None = 'html') -> str:
    if isinstance(id, User):
        user = id
        id = user.id
        name = personal_appeal(user)

    name = escape_string(name, escape=escape)

    if name is None:
        name = "N/A"

    if id is not None:
        return f'<a href="tg://user?id={id}">{name}</a>'
    else:
        return name
```

Basically, this code generates a link from a user name - user ID pair. As you can see, the name is HTML escaped by default.

There is, however, one user, which breaks this code somehow, by their unusual first name, and here is the actual sequence of characters they use:

```
'$̴̢̛̙͈͚̎̓͆͑.̸̱̖͑͒ ̧̡͉̺̬͎̯.̸̧̢̠̺̮̬͙͛̓̀̐́.̵̦͑̉͌͌̎͘ ̞ ̷̡͈̤̓̀͋͗͊̈́̑̽͝'
```

Screenshot of the result of the same code run against this first name:

[image: bad markup]

As you can see, telegram seems to be lost in the markup. The link escapes onto other unrelated characters, and the `<b>` tag is broken, too.

This is the actual string which is being sent to the telegram servers (except for the ids, those I redacted out):

```
 <u>Рейтинг игроков чата</u>:

 1. <a href="tg://user?id=1">andy alexanderson</a> (<b>40</b>)
 2. <a href="tg://user?id=2">$̴̢̛̙͈͚̎̓͆͑.̸̱̖͑͒ ̧̡͉̺̬͎̯.̸̧̢̠̺̮̬͙͛̓̀̐́.̵̦͑̉͌͌̎͘ ̞ ̷̡͈̤̓̀͋͗͊̈́̑̽͝</a> (<b>40</b>)
 3. <a href="tg://user?id=3">: )</a> (<b>0</b>)

⏱️ <i>Рейтинг составлен 1 минуту назад</i>.
⏭️ <i>Следующее обновление через 28 минут</i>.
```

Seems like the only odd thing in this markup is the nickname, though.

Is this a Telegram bug?

Can something be done to mitigate this, so that my users wouldn't be able to escape the HTML markup? **I am willing to sacrifice the correctness of their name representation** (due to the fact that such users willingly obfuscate their names), but **I need to somehow be able to tell apart something which would break the markup**.

**Or maybe there is some UTF-16 <-> UTF-8 encoding stuff going on that I'm missing out on?**

Framework used: `python-telegram-bot`.
Python version: `3.10.12`.

Comment: I'm surprised they're not called [tony the pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4799172). This is [zalgo text](https://lingojam.com/ZalgoText) (or maybe some other name, but that's one way to generate it). I'm afraid I can't help with this problem itself, though

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, at least you hinted me in the direction of stripping those characters out, once I know how that thing is called, lol

Comment: @roganjosh, hey, I found a way to strip those characters out, if you're interested: I posted the answer.

Comment: @roganjosh you're right, didn't think from this perspective. Changed it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roganjosh pointed out, this turns out to be a so-called "zalgo" sequence of characters. To remove the zalgo characters, I first found [this decode function from an old JS library called lunicode.js](https://github.com/combatwombat/Lunicode.js/blob/master/lunicode.js#L460). I found it by reversing [this zalgo-text encoder-decoder website](https://lingojam.com/ZalgoText).

It turned out to be a very simple function, so here it is written in python:

```
def remove_zalgo(txt: str) -> str:
    return ''.join([
        char
        for char in txt
        if ord(char) < 768 or ord(char) > 865
    ])
```

Now my markup doesn't break, and there are no zalgo characters in names of my users. I think, it's a win :)

Comment: Have you checked that this doesn't strip _all_ diacritics, even the ones that are sensible?

Comment: @roganjosh unfortunately, it does strip all of them. It's an easy way out, and it seems sufficient for my app. I don't think distinguishing between sensible and nonsensical diacritics is a solvable task, though, if you work outside language context.

Comment: I don't like it overall. For your implementation, I bet you could have a heuristic to judge in some way on the number of diacritics you will accept before you strip them all. roganjosh is just my handle but I take it quite personally when it's misused (people calling me Rogan etc.). I shouldn't, but I do anyway

Comment: @roganjosh you're absolutely right, and I agree with you 100% on that you shouldn't misuse people's handles, and I should respect that in my app. However, so far my app's users are mostly Russian speakers, and the Russian language doesn't use diacritics at all, so I'll be using this fix, until the bug is fixed in Telegram bot API( [I reported it here](https://bugs.telegram.org/c/35126)). I wouldn't use this fix myself, if I had a way to get rid of the root cause, which seems to be the way how Telegram servers fail to parse HTML tags, if diacritics are involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/):

```py
from unidecode import unidecode
print(unidecode('$̴̢̛̙͈͚̎̓͆͑.̸̱̖͑͒ ̧̡͉̺̬͎̯.̸̧̢̠̺̮̬͙͛̓̀̐́.̵̦͑̉͌͌̎͘ ̞ ̷̡͈̤̓̀͋͗͊̈́̑̽͝<'))
# output:
# $. ..  <
```

And with a more meaningful input:

```py
from unidecode import unidecode
print(unidecode('ᴮᴵᴳᴮᴵᴿᴰ'))
# output:
# BIGBIRD
```

Comment: it's a pretty good lib for transliteration, but it turns everything into latin ascii characters, afaik. So it's too much of collateral damage for users who use anything but latin. But thanks for a good lib!

Comment: there is a lot more options but I admit it's hard to find something that work. It works fine for names though I think? By the way, if you want to look up more solution on this topic, this is related to "unicode normalization". There a lot more related keywords such as "unicode vector attack", etc which are also related on some degree @winwin

Comment: those aren't names, unfortunately. People mostly set as their names whatever they can come up with in Telegram. And even if they were, I wouldn't want to transliterate them, because my app is mostly cyrillic.